# pitest report can't mix JUnit 4 and JUnit 5 tests

Tags: java, mutation-testing, pitest

Recently, I introduced Pitest as the mutation testing tool to our team to diagnose test quality, and we loved it.

In our codebase, we have lots of preexisting JUnit 4, and now we're writing all of our new unit tests in JUnit 5.
Unfortunately, even after adding Pitest JUnit 5 plugin when we try to run the mutation testing goal `mvn org.pitest:pitest-maven:mutationCoverage`, and it only picks up JUnit 4 tests and ignores JUnit 5 tests.

We want our report to contain JUnit 4 and 5 tests. Is there a way(hack) to generate a report mixed with JUnit 4 and 5?

Comment: What version of pitest are you using?

Comment: You're right! We upgraded to the latest version: `1.7.1` and it's working now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed by henry's comment, I fixed the issue by upgrading to the latest version of pitest. These versions worked for me:

```xml
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.pitest</groupId>
                <artifactId>pitest-maven</artifactId>
                <version>1.7.1</version>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.pitest</groupId>
                        <artifactId>pitest-junit5-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>0.14</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
```

Answer (score 2):

For **Junit5**, I use this "**build**" section in my pom.xml

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.pitest</groupId>
                <artifactId>pitest-maven</artifactId>
                <version>1.7.6</version>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.pitest</groupId>
                        <artifactId>pitest-junit5-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>0.15</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

and I run pi-test with this **command**:

```
 mvn test-compile org.pitest:pitest-maven:mutationCoverage
```